# Is critical path/gate exist in quantum computation?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

In a quantum algorithm, are there any quantum gates more important than the other gates? For example, if the same error happens to two H gates in a circuit, can we determine which gate has a larger impact on the result?

Also, can we determine which logical qubit is more important in a quantum algorithm and we can only apply error mitigation/correction to this qubit?